# Facebook: Client token must be embedded in your client code

Tags: android, facebook

Facebook throws the warm error, how to resolve it?

```
GraphRequest: Starting with v13 of the SDK, a client token must be embedded in your client code before making Graph API calls. Visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#client-token to learn how to implement this change.
```

I already added to Manifest

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

Version:

```
"com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:12.1.0"
```

Comment: You need to add the client token, as the page mentioned in the error message explains.

Comment: @CBroe : Sorry but i did not get you? Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @Mak13 elaborate on what, exactly? The page mentioned in the error message quoted above explains what needs to be done, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#client-token

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks. I will check and follow the steps now.

Answer (score 5):

In strings.xml you need to have

```
<string name="facebook_client_token">123456</string>
```

And you can find your facebook client id by following these steps in your facebook developers page:

On the **Dashboard**, navigate to **Settings** > **Advanced** > **Security** > **Client token.**

You can read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#client-token

Comment: You need to add it inside info.plist in Xcode as well under FacebookClientToken key